# What are the main differences of Sphinx and Doxygen?

Tags: c++, opencv, python-sphinx, doxygen, documentation-generation

I want to prepare a documentation for a collection of projects, modules and libraries in the field of computer vision (mostly written in c++). To this end I had a look on *OpenCV* documentation and as you may know *OpenCV* 2.4.x documentation is based on [*Sphinx*](https://sphinx-doc.org/) and It was the exact solution that I was seeking for. the nice features of Sphinx are:

1. **Hierarchical structure** of modules in semantic point of view. For example *Kalman Filter* is a child of *Motion Analysis and Object Tracking* module
2. You can add **images** and also mathematics **formulas**
3. Pretty good embedded **search engine**

But I realized that the c++ version of OpenCV3.0 is documented based on [*Doxygen*](https://www.doxygen.nl/) and I don't know why! because it is not as interesting as *Sphinx*.
I know that *Doxygen* can compile your code and extract your comments which is an useful feature. I also know that there are libraries (like *breathe*) which could act as a bridge between *Doxygen* and *Sphinx*.

**Now my questions are:**

1. Are *Sphinx* and *Doxygen* alternatives of each other or they could be used alongside?
2. Does *Doxygen* have the mentioned features of *Sphinx*?
3. Which documentation engine (*Sphinx*, *Doxygen* or other engines) do you prefer for my problem?

Comment: The Sphinx says it is a Python documentation tool.  I know Doxygen can parse C++ language.

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. But I am wondering how is the c++ version of OpenCV documented using Sphinx!!

Comment: This is an excellent, but perhaps a little broad, question. It prompted me to ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594254/why-did-opencv-3-change-its-documentation-tool-from-sphinx-to-doxygen. As for how OpenCV2 is documented with sphinx, it uses the sphinx c++ domain, and is relatively straightforward to follow in the cmake build scheme.

Answer (score 16):

This answer addresses point 2 of your question.

Yes, doxygen partly has those features.

- You can have [math formulas](http://www.doxygen.nln/manual/formulas.html), that can be rendered either through a local Latex install, or through MathJax, a Javascript rendering library. As with Latex, these can be either "embedded" into text, or as a separate unit in the text flow.
- It also includes a [search engine](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/searching.html).
- You can easily [include images](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage).

For example, the two lines below will add the same image both in html and latex generated output:

```
  \image latex my_image.png "My image" width=10cm
  \image html my_image.png "My image" width=10cm
```

I think I recall that in html, caption and width are ignored ? But Doxygen is really flexible, so if the command above isn't enough, you can just add them as html code:

```
<img src="my_image.png"  ...additional html attributes...>
```

Doxygen supports also a lot of [regular html commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html) that you can directly include in your comment block.

I have no experience with Sphinx other than building Opencv manual, but what I can add about Doxygen (that I use on a day to day basis) is that it is really flexible, but this doesn't mean it's always the best choice. Pages can get cluttered and if the comment additional code is badly designed, it can get in your way.

For completeness, one the best showcases of what doxygen can do (besides the Doxygen web site of course), is the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/). Take a look.